# How to trigger DAG between the airflow clusters?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I have two different Airflow clusters, basically need to trigger the DAG which is running on another cluster.

Is it possible to do with `TriggerDagRunOperator`? or any Sensors can be used for this?

I find this link useful, but does it work on multiple clusters?

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/airflow-lesson-1-triggerdagrunoperator-siddharth-anand

Comment: With a cluster, you mean multiple instances of Airflow? If so, how about using the API to trigger a DAG from an instance of Airflow to another Instance of Airflow?
Using TriggerDagRunOperator I don't think that will work.

Comment: @nicor88: there are two different AWS environment is used for these Airflow instances, thought of using Lambda for this, but somehow it wasn't approved.. so looking for other options..

Comment: Have a look to this: https://airflow.apache.org/api.html might be an option.